# DOS INT 8 based moving asterisk not working

Tags: assembly, timer, int, dos, nasm

i am trying to code a TSR (DOS 16BIT), in which every tick of the INT8 moves an asterisk forward around the perimeter of the screen. I have 4 subroutines with different increments of the '*' position corresponding to the respective screen borders. However, the code hangs and i cannot run it all at once in the debugger either, as it depends upon the interrupt. please suggest a solution

```
pos:        dw      158,3998,3838,0
routine:    dw      subrt1,subrt2,subrt3,subrt4

subrt1:     
            add di,2
            cmp di,[pos]
            jnz exit
            add bx,2

exit:       ret 

subrt2:     add di,160
            cmp di,[pos+2]
            jnz exit
            add bx,2
            ret 

subrt3:     sub di,2
            cmp di,[pos+4]
            jnz exit
            add bx,2
            ret
subrt4:     sub di,160
            cmp di,[pos+6]
            jnz exit
            mov bx,0
            ret


timer:      push ax

            mov ax,0xb800
            mov es,ax

            mov word[es:di],0x720
            call [routine+bx]           
            mov word[es:di],0x742

            mov al,0x20
            out 0x20,al
            pop ax
            iret

start:      xor ax,ax
            xor bx,bx
            mov es,ax
            cli
            mov word[es:8*4],timer
            mov word[es:8*4+2],cs
            sti
            mov dx,start
            add dx,15
            mov cl,4
            shr dx,cl
            mov ax,0x3100
            int 0x21
```

Comment: Don't forget to state what platform you're trying to write code for.  But the most obvious problem here is that you're not chaining the original int 8h handler, as far as I can see.   You should chain to the original 8h handler before executing your own code.

Comment: A TSR ? Did you fall through a wormhole back to the early 1980s ???

Comment: No my friend i am from a third world country. hope that answers your question, but please answer mine too :)

Comment: James, no problem with chaining thats tested and correct see.............cli
            mov word[es:8*4],timer
            mov word[es:8*4+2],cs
            sti..........

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what value 3T838 is supposed to represent in the pos definition. I'm not familiar with the 'T' notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you fix your problems, which are mostly about correct preservation of the register state. See the comments.

```
org 0x100 ;; missing?
jmp start ;; missing?

pos:        dw      158,3998,3840,0 ;; what is 3T838?
routine:    dw      subrt1,subrt2,subrt3,subrt4
state       dw      0 ;; storage for bx
curpos      dw      0 ;; storage for di
oldisr      dd      0 ;; address of old timer interrupt ISR

subrt1:     
            add di,2
            cmp di,[pos]
            jnz exit
            add bx,2

exit:       ret 

subrt2:     add di,160
            cmp di,[pos+2]
            jnz exit
            add bx,2
            ret 

subrt3:     sub di,2
            cmp di,[pos+4]
            jnz exit
            add bx,2
            ret

subrt4:     sub di,160
            cmp di,[pos+6]
            jnz exit
            mov bx,0
            ret


timer:      push ax
            push bx ;; must preserve bx
            push di ;; must preserve di
            push ds ;; must preserve ds
            push es ;; must preserve es

            push cs ;; must load cs into ds to access pos,routine,state,curpos
            pop ds

            mov ax,0xb800
            mov es,ax

            mov di, [curpos] ;; must retrieve di from storage
            mov bx, [state] ;; must retrieve bx from storage

            mov word[es:di],0x720

            call [routine+bx]

            mov word[es:di],0x72A ;; you need 42 decimal (2A hex), not 42 hex

            mov [curpos], di ;; must preserve di between ints
            mov [state], bx ;; must preserve bx between ints

            ;mov al,0x20 ;; remove int acknowledge as the old ISR will do it for us
            ;out 0x20,al

            pop es ;; must restore es
            pop ds ;; must restore ds
            pop di ;; must restore di
            pop bx ;; must restore bx
            pop ax

            ;iret ;; instead of direct iret continue in the old ISR
            jmp far [cs:oldisr] ;; to prevent undesired effects (hangs/crashes)

start:      xor ax,ax
            ; xor bx,bx ;; unnecessary
            mov es,ax
            cli

            push word[es:8*4] ;; remember old ISR address
            push word[es:8*4+2]
            pop word[oldisr+2]
            pop word[oldisr]

            mov word[es:8*4],timer
            mov word[es:8*4+2],cs
            sti
            mov dx,start
            add dx,15
            mov cl,4
            shr dx,cl
            mov ax,0x3100
            int 0x21
```

Comment: Sorry guys, thats a typo introduced while copy-pasting the code. its 3838

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on TSRs, but I do see a number of problems here.

First, I agree with James Youngman's comment-- I don't see where you're chaining the original interrupt handler. The code you quoted in your followup comment to James is simply the code for safely replacing the existing interrupt hander (disabling interrupts during the replacement so there is no race condition). That's not enough. You need to save the segment:address of that handler and call into that handler when you are finished with your handler.

Second, as I indicated in my comment, I don't understand that 3T838 value in pos and don't understand how the assembler could process that. But I might be missing something.

Third, you can't anticipate any context when you enter the handler. You are branching based on bx ("call [routine+bx]"), but bx is not set to anything between the "timer:" label and that call instruction. Indeed, bx can be anything here. If you are expecting bx to be a running value from interrupt to interrupt, you need to maintain its value in a separate variable, moving that variable into bx at the start of the handler, and saving it back out before you leave. This goes for the di register as well, which I don't observe as being initialized *anywhere* in your code.

Fourth, I'm not entirely confident about the parameters you are passing to int 21h/ah=31h; the documentation I am able to find indicates that dx is supposed to be set to the number of paragraphs that your program uses. You are loading the address of "start:" and multiplying that by 16 (which is indeed the size of a paragraph). You may want to double-check the docs on this; I'm not sure what is supposed to go here.

Good luck. I understand that writing TSRs was a challenging feat even in the days when they were commonplace.